# How can I add one or more paths to Ansible search path (for files or templates)?

Tags: configuration, ansible, search-path

In my case I am mounting my Ansible code inside a Docker container under `/ansible/playbook/`. Under this directory you will see the `roles`, `inventories`

I would like to mount another directory that contains some RPM files.

In Ansible I have this code:

```
---
- name: copy ZooKeeper rpm file
  copy:
    src: zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    dest: /tmp

- name: install ZooKeeper rpm package
  yum:
    name: /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    state: present
```

The problem is that ZooKeeper does not exist in any of the default search paths:

```
Could not find or access 'zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm'
Searched in:
    /ansible/playbook/roles/kafka/files/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    /ansible/playbook/roles/kafka/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    /ansible/playbook/roles/kafka/tasks/files/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    /ansible/playbook/roles/kafka/tasks/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    /ansible/playbook/files/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
    /ansible/playbook/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm
```

How can I add extra search paths to this list for example:

```
    /ansible/rpms/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm//
```

I don't want to hardcode absolute paths (if this works) in the Ansible code. I would like to provide something like: `ANSIBLE_EXTRA_SEARCH_PATH`.

How can I do this?

PS: I cannot create a symlink to my RPM directory inside the already mounted `/ansible/playbook` because Docker will see it and a bad link (not being able to read it, because the target directory, the one containing the RPM files is not part of the Docker container file system.)

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to

- put the rpm in *any_path*
- link *any_path* to /ansible/playbook/rpms
- use *src: rpms/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm*

Comment: Actually this will not work because: 1. you cannot create hard links to directories (or at least I did not find a way to do it). 2. Soft links are not properly visible inside Docker container because the original linked directory (`any_path`) is not visible inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lookup with a list of paths and the `first_found` query:

```
- name: install ZooKeeper rpm package
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}/zookeeper-3.4.13-1.x86_64.rpm"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ query('first_found', { 'paths': mypaths}) }}"
  vars:
    mypaths: ['/tmp', '/opt/other_location/somedir/', '/rpms']
```

More information at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#selecting-files-and-templates-based-on-variables